# Is there an SQL alternative like Python's Shelve for Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, python, nosql, persistence

Shelve is an ultra-simple No-SQL persistence layer which allows you to trivially persist a mapping of objects. It's a commonly used package in Python because it allows you to trivially add persistence to any application.

It's simplistic nature means it's somewhat limited - but it's surprisingly useful. You can map any arbitrary hashable key onto any serializable object.

Does something like this exist for Android? I'm writing a very simple app, and I've noticed that I'm spending a lot of time faffing around with table structures, select & insert statements. That's the sort of thing I almost never do in Python since I'd usually have some kind of NoSQL alternative.

I'm not expecting to to work exactly the same way - clearly Python and Java are languages with very different characteristics. I just want something that nearly as simple to use and requires less manual SQL faffing.

One more thing - this is a fairly trivial app. I'd prefer to introduce the bare minimum of additional project dependencies. Preference will be given to solutions which require nothing more than the Android APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said preference to Java API answers so I probably won't get preference, but Couchbase Mobile is the best Android No-SQL I have ever come across.

http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-mobile-for-android/current

Comment: Yes, I looked at Couch. It's certainly very popular. My concern is that it's rather more complex than a shelve type database even if it is probably higher performance and ultimately a better solution if we decide to continue the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SharedPrefences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) from [DataStore](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). It's pretty much what you need. You don't need full SQLite power for this.

Comment: I ruled out SharedPreferences because it only seems to be able to store primatives. What if I wanted to store my objects in SP? My impression is that it is not able to handle this kind of thing at all.